# Where in the Quran does it says Angel Mikail is responsible for bringing rain and thunder?

Tags: quran, uloom-al-hadith, science, malaikah, belief

Well now everyone knows that Earth isn't the only planet with atmosphere and weather. There could be millions of non habitable planets with strange atmospheric conditions. In such a case claiming that an angel stays above us in the sky and always controls and looks after the weather of our planet earth seems a little outdated idea. Because if that's the case then someone could ask this way, "then who controls the atmosphere and weather in other planets where no creature lives and why?"

I searched for reference in the Quran, whether such a claim is seen or not. But I couldn't find the reference. but most of the web sites while claiming the duty of Angel claims the above way?

are there any reference in the Quran? Is that a hadith? If so, is that an authentic one?

Comment: The Qur'an quotes Mikail or Michael or Mikaal, but it doesn't attribute any responsibility to him. If such thing may exist than in the sunnah and I'd even assume that the source might be discussed. As the Qur'an actually say otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As‘salaamu alaikum.

I have seen the Angel Micheal‘s name mentioned only once in the Qur‘an (2:98) and nothing is said about his Angelic responsibilities. Nor have I personally read any lore about the Angel Micheal in the hadith literature.

All that I have read about Micheal is that he is the Arch Angel of war, but that info comes from Jewish/Christian sources. Their lore is unreliable at best, seeing how they cling to the idea that the Shaytaan is an Angel who set himself up as a rival to Allah and got himself expelled from the Angelic assembly. Clearly, their lore is wrong about quite a bit, so we can‘t trust it.

However, in the Qur‘an, Allah says that it is HE HIMSELF Who is responsible for thunder and lightning, (13:12-13).

I hope you find this answer helpful. Ma‘as‘salaam.